# How to boot to program on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi

What I want to do is mimic an operating system without reinventing the wheel. When my Pi boots up I want it to have a custom bootup so it goes straight into my program.

Comment: Possibly you may want to move this question to [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The feature you're looking for is generally called *kiosk mode*.

Answer (score 1):

What SO it have? Raspian? LibreElec? another one?
If you are on raspian you can edit `/etc/rc.local` and put over there the commands to start the programs

Answer (score 0):

okay, but basically you should not try messing with the init process ( pid 1 )  ran by systemd or the old-school sysVinit

you should look up the (originally obsolete since 1983 ) , but still used [/etc/rc.local which you can easily re-enable](https://www.2daygeek.com/linux-systemd-auto-restart-services-when-down/)  , in openwrt and some raspi distros it is already set up

there you might start your command with screen e.g. :

```
screen -dmS nameOfScreen command
```

so you could reattach (`screen -x`) and send keyboard input , but you can also just send to syslog